# Swift - Different pngData() sizes in different iOS in unit tests

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, rotation, uiimage

I'm testing a rotation of an image on my Swift project using unit tests.

I'm getting different results to `pngData()` when I test with iOS 13.7 then when I test with iOS 11.2.

Also strange and I think it's related and also my real problem is that -

On iOS 13.7 comparing 2 images - static image and rotated image - return that they are the same data size.

On iOS 11.2 - my static image changed its data size by X AMOUNT and my rotated image changed its data size by Y AMOUNT and now they have different data sizes and my test fails.

The rotate func -

```
func cld_rotate(_ degree: Float) -> UIImage? {
    var newSize = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.size).applying(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: cld_radians(from: Double(degree)))).size
    // Trim off the extremely small float value to prevent core graphics from rounding it up
    newSize.width = floor(newSize.width)
    newSize.height = floor(newSize.height)
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, self.scale)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    
    // Move origin to middle
    context.translateBy(x: newSize.width/2, y: newSize.height/2)
    // Rotate around middle
    context.rotate(by: cld_radians(from: Double(degree)))
    // Draw the image at its center
    draw(in: CGRect(x: -self.size.width/2, y: -self.size.height/2, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
    
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    return newImage
}
```

Any idea about why `pngData()` is not the same used in 2 different iOS? And why the rotated image change its data size by a different amount than the static one?

Comment: See [PNG: File size and optimization software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_size_and_optimization_software).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG images are compressed. Rotating the image will likely require that it be re-compressed, which may yield different output. I would expect the filesize to change slightly, since compression algorithms can yield different file sizes based on different input data. (I originally stated that PNG images used lossy compression, but I was mistaken.)

To me the question is how does iOS 13.7 preserve the file size on rotation. I wonder if it is able to recognize a 90 degree rotation and transform the compressed image data somehow, where iOS 11.2 isn't able to do that? (My guess is that the image compression/decompression algorithm got smarter between iOS 11.2 and iOS 13.7, and now it's able to recognize a 90 degree rotation and use an algorithm on the data without having to decompresss and re-compress the image.)

I'm not sure what you are saying about a static image. Are you saying that you open the PNG image into a UIImage and then export it back to a PNG without transforming it?

Comment: My mistake. I've edited my answer. However, compression algorithms like Huffman (which is apparently part of the DEFLATE compression that PNG uses) have different compression ratios for different data, and it makes sense that rotating an image would cause changes in the output file-size.)

Comment: By static image, I mean a local image that is in the project that is already rotated i just turn it to UIImage and from there to data via pngData(). rotated image is another local image that I turn to UIImage then rotate it and then turn to data via pngData()